# TFS 2008: Overwrite Label on file

Tags: tfs, label

I'm trying to apply Label on a file, but I obtain this error because Label already exists on an old version of file:

**TF203007: Cannot create the label because the version controlled item $/MyProj/MyFile.cs already exists or has been specified more than once.**

I want move Label from an old version to Latest.

Is it possible?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

A very easy workaround (if it's allowed in your case) to resolve this error mesg is (especially when everybody is standing behind you to fix this issue on urgent basis):

- Just change the buildnumber.txt file (The file which holds the last successful buildnumber "number" in it) and bump the number to a new value i.e. if you are getting an error that TFS>. ... can't label ... file and during that build time the build label that TFS was trying to apply (lets say) is : TFS_RELEASE_BUILD_5, then, just bump the build number to 10 or 20 or 50, i.e. the next build number your build script will generate automatically will be either 11, 21 or 51.

Problem resolved.

My case:

1. I created a branch "11.0" sometime 2 weeks back. On this branch, we created builds from 1 to 10. Build label was in format: TUD_COR_11.0.0.1 ..to 10.
2. Yesterday, I deleted 11.0 branch.
3. Yesterday, we had to recreate this branch again from a new source branch so what we did was:

   a. deleted 11.0 branch. checked in the change so branch is gone now.

   b. Deleted all the builds that were created by the build defintion and finally deleted the build definition (as other team members wanted me to create a new build definition for the new 11.0 branch (to be created from a new source branch) again from scratch. While creating the build definitions, I successfully saw the "tick" marks against labels/etc/anything related to existing build definitions were going to delete as per the Delete operation.
4. Now I created new 11.0 branch again from latest data from the source branch as of today.
5. Created the build definitions again.
6. Created COR build again with build label TUD_COR_11.0.0.1. Now TFS gave me the similar "error mesg" as mentioned in the thread above.

Possible resolution:

A. Delete the file "as per the build log" where TFS Label operation is failing. You can use sidekick -OR TF label command. Note: This can be time consuming as what if you delete the label from the file (OR delete this file under this label i.e. this label is not applied to this label anymore).

******NOTE: Here we are NOT deleting the file from source control.*  just removing the file from the label concept

B.  OR just increase the buildnumber.txt .. that the build script uses to generate the build label i.e. if my buildnumber.txt (which is somewhere in the source control branch tree), it contained a value of "0" and it was creating build "1" with label: TUD_COR_11.0.0.1 (where branch is 11.0 and build series is 11.0.0.1) i.e. ... format. Now if I just change the value of this buildnumber.txt to "10" (why as that was the last build number we successfully created when we HAD 11.0 branch earlier (before we deleted it).. so I bumped the buildnumber value to 10 i.e. now if I run the build definition again (i.e. queue the build), build script will generate a new build with number: 11 i.e. with build label "TUD_COR_11.0.0.11". Problem solved in few SECONDS here. Nobody in the company raised any doubts in doing this as this was a development branch so they didn't care what build number we(SCM team) are providing to them. They just wanted a successful build.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it is trying to apply the label to a version of that file that already has that label.  If you use `tf label`, it will move the label if it can, so you're doing that the right way.

One thing to check is whether the version in the workspace is the version that you want to label.  Otherwise, specify the versionspec (e.g. the following will label the latest version of the file regardless of what you currently have in your workspace):

`tf label "$/MyProj/MyFile.cs" /version:T /server:http://tfs:8080`

If you could post the `tf label` command line you're using it might also help.

(edit:  the tf command above would work for tfs 2005 and 2008.  You'll need to specify the project collection instead of server for tfs 2010).